# How can I DROP COLUMN in Microsoft SQL Server with a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE tblUser
DROP COLUMN Mobile
```

Error:

> ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Mobile failed because one or more objects access this column.

This column had values in Table. How can I delete all objects that access this column?

How can I `DROP COLUMN` with values?

how can do it with code? How can I delete all constraints in column automatically?

Comment: First check what use it (`VIEW WITH SCHEMABINDING, CONSTRAINTS, INDEXES, COMPUTED COLUMNS`...) You cannot just drop column when something else depends on it

Comment: See table definition for indexes/computed columns and constraints or check in **Object Explorer in SSMS**

Comment: Seriously, you do **DDL** on DB and don't know how to check it?

Comment: how can do it with code? how can Delete all constraints in column Automatic؟

Comment: You need to **know what those constraints are** and what their names are in order to drop them; there's nothing in SQL Server to say `DROP ALL CONSTRAINTS` and just do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Mobile failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Your column won't be deleted. Because one column or multiple columns are getting reference from this column that you want to delete.

So first, you will have to find in which table your column is being referenced by below query.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME'
```

It will show you all constraints of all tables of your current database. You need to find it and remove the constraint. After that your column will be deleted successfully because there is no reference of your column in any table.

To remove constraint from column - use below query

```
alter table tablename
drop constraint constraintid
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) is a great tool. I will search for your all the objects which are using the targeted object.

You can easily find where your column is being used, then simply you can modify or drop that objects too.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query to find the constraints name for particular tablename

```
  SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLENAME'
```

Noe you can see the constraints name under constraint_name column, drop all constraint using below syntax

```
  ALTER TABLE TABLENAME DROP CONSTRAINT CONSTRATINTSNAME
```

After that you can use below statement to drop the column

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME DROP COLUMN COLUMNNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what those constraints are and what their names are in order to drop them; there's nothing in SQL Server to say DROP ALL CONSTRAINTS and just do it. –  marc_s yesterday